# matrix android

Tags: android, canvas

Здравствуйте)
Борюсь с матрицами в адроиде.Раньше работал на opengl ,там всё нормальнов какой последовательности всё сделал то и будет...А тут ... какая-то!
post pre set ...

Мне нужно:

1. Сначала перенести картинку в центр
2. Отскалировать её под размеры экрана
3. Вертеть

Код:

```
m.postTranslate(cxCompass - ((float)compass.getWidth()/2),
                cyCompass - ((float)compass.getHeight()/2));

if(getMeasuredWidth()<getMeasuredHeight())
    m.preScale((float) getMeasuredWidth()/((float)compass.getWidth()),(float) getMeasuredWidth()/((float)compass.getWidth()));
else
    m.preScale((float) getMeasuredHeight()/((float)compass.getHeight()),(float) getMeasuredHeight()/((float)compass.getHeight()));

m.preRotate((float) ((-direction)),
            (float) compass.getWidth() / 2,
            (float) compass.getHeight() / 2);
```

Если выполнить только `postTranslate` всё хорошо, но когда я пытаюсь как то отскалировать, например тем что сейчас в коде. Всё смещается немного вправо и вниз. Почему? Как нужно правильно и в какой последовательности сделать, чтобы получить желаемое? И объясните, пожалуйста, префексы к функ. матрицы - `post set pre`...
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

> > Всё смещаетс немного вправо и вниз.Почему?

А все очень просто. Когда Вы делаете изменение размеров, должна быть "точка опоры" - относительно чего все и изменяется. Точно также и при повороте.

Осталось выяснить, где же эта точка. Ответ просто - в начале координат (0,0). Но вот загвоздка - в OpenGL эта точна будет по центру, а при 2D режиме (где собственно Вы "боритесь"), точка находится вверху слева. Именно поэтому, когда картинку увеличиваете, то она будет смещаться вниз-вправо. (а в openGL оно будет расширятся в разные стороны относительно центра. В каком то смысле это выглядит "естественней".). Поэтому при повороте учитывайте это и все будет ок.

Answer (score 1):

В доках же говориться чем отличается

```
pre: M' = M * S(sx, sy) 
post: M' = S(sx, sy) * M
```

Т.е. с какого конца в мультипликативную последовательность будет дописана новая матрица транформации. Я думаю надо просто придти к единообразию и везде писать post. (Ну или наоборот pre)

Comment: Я тоже так думал,но когда я делаю всё pre ,почему то не в центре а немного правее и ниже центра

Comment: Вот каким образом он вообще может при скалировании смещаться,это как такое возможноОо там совсем не на такой вектор умножается чтобы хоть какое то смещение было

Comment: @JustixLoL смещаться может если центр осей не в центре картинки. А если все post поставить?

Comment: если всё Post то крутится не вокруг своей точки а вокруг точки за своим изображ. уже.
"смещаться может если центр осей не в центре картинки" - 
Ну так как центр может быть не там,если , например, без scale картинка точно в центре располагается?

Comment: Дополнил preScale ещё двумя аргументами центра картинки(width/2 height/2)
И всё сделал pre.Вроде работает.Сейчас на другом телефоне проверю

Comment: Да , заработало!Спасибо за наводку!